# How to get language code of a field in a node

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a requirement where in hook_node_insert I need to get the language code of a field

What I have tried is

```
$langcode = $node->{$field_name}->langcode
```

But this returns null. Any suggestions?

And is it possible that different fields in a node have different langcode?

Comment: Use kint to explain $node, there you can find multiple functions to get lan code, must be a function getDefaultLanguage() or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getLangcode](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemBase.php/function/FieldItemBase%3A%3AgetLangcode/8.2.x)
Try with:

```
$node->{$field_name}->getLangcode()
```